# Java : Thread with or without anonymous runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently learning about thread in Java and I saw these examples on the net.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code....
    }
});
```

and

```
Thread t2 = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code....
    }
};
```

What's the differences between creating thread with and without creating anonymous runnable?
Which one is correct way to use a thread?

Comment: Both are "correct" but I like the first better.  Creating sub-classes of Thread is usually the wrong approach.  Creating an object like a Runnable than can be executed by a Thread, an ExecutorService or some other means is considered superior in terms of separation of concerns and flexibility.